# How to hide Choose File Button from Vaadin Paper Input [File]

Tags: java, gwt, polymer, vaadin, polymer-1.0

My Code goes like this,

```
    PaperInput filePaperInput = new PaperInput();
    filePaperInput.setLabel("File");
    filePaperInput.setType("file");
    filePaperInput.setAlwaysFloatLabel(true);
```

How to hide the "Choose File" button rendered in the UI?

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>com.vaadin.polymer</groupId> 
    <artifactId>vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements</artifactId> 
    <version>1.2.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try using an Upload instead. Upload u = new Upload();
  u.setImmediate(true);

Comment: When an upload is set to immediate you don't get a browse button, just a single button that when clicked allows your user to select a file

Comment: @ChrisM I am had updated the dependency am using in my module. Could u guide me which is the jar u are suggesting.